# $H^s(A)=0 \iff H^s_\infty(A)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

I have the following exercise: *Show that $H^s(A)=0 \iff H^s_\infty(A)=0$ for $A\subset \mathbb R^d$.* Here $H^s(A)$ is he Hausdorff measure of the set $A$, so $H^s(A):=\lim_{\delta\to 0^+} H^s_\delta(A)$.

Now, it is clear that, since $H^s(A)\geq H^s_\delta(A)$ for any $\delta$, if $H^s(A)=0$ then $H^s_\infty(A)=0$.

How to do the converse? Do you have some hints to give me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the idea: if $H^s_\infty(A) = 0$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a cover of $A$ by sets $E_k$ with 
$$\sum_k (\mathrm{diam}\ E_k)^s < \epsilon.$$
In particular, $(\mathrm{diam}\ E_k)^s < \epsilon$ for each $k$, so you in fact have $$H^s_{\epsilon^{1/s}} (A)< \epsilon.$$

This is true for every $\epsilon > 0$. What happens as $\epsilon \to 0^+$?

Comment: We have that $H^s_{\epsilon^{1/s}}(A)\to 0$, so $H^s(A)=0$, right?

Comment: If $0 \le f(\epsilon) < \epsilon$ and $\epsilon \to 0^+$ then...

Comment: Then $f(\epsilon)\to 0.$

Comment: And by definition $H^s(A) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} H^s_{\epsilon^{1/s}}(A)$.